# Is it possible to add title to R Markdown table? (by using Markdown features)

Tags: r-markdown, markdown

How can I add title to a R Markdown table by using Markdown features.

My codes:

```
| Name                   | Surname             | Team                        |
|:----------------------:|:-------------------:|:---------------------------:|
| Luka                   | Modric              | Real Madrid CF              |
| Arda                   | Guler               | Real Madrid CF              |
```

It produces a table. But, desired output is this:
[image: table]

I tried to merge rows like that is not a caption, that is a value. But, I couldn't get the result.
Is there any suggestion?

Note. I will knit to HTML.

Comment: for example `# title`